# Google Maps API V3: fromContainerPixelToLatLng

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working on a project that requires that I have a div stacked above a Google Map. However, I need to pass the `mousemove` event of the div to the Map. To do that, I need to find the LatLng co-ordinates from the map container pixel co-ordinate (since triggering the Maps `mousemove` event requires the LatLng co-ordinates).

Is there any other way to pass the mousemove event from the div to the map, and if not, how do I go from the Map container co-ordinates to LatLng. I read that doing so requires creating a dummy overlay, and then using the `getProjection()` on that to get a `MapCanvasProjection`, and finally calling the `fromContainerPixelToLatLng()`. Is there any simpler way or do I really have to create a dummy overlay first?

Comment: see at http://code.google.com/intl/vi/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#Projections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is the way you have to do it.  I was reluctant at first, too, since it seemed like such overkill, but once I did it everything worked great.  Here's an example implementation with a convenient `delayedInit()` callback:

```js
function Dummy(map) {
    this.setMap(map);
}
Dummy.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
Dummy.prototype.draw = function() {
    if (!this.ready) { 
        this.ready = true; 
        google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'ready'); 
    } 
}
Dummy.prototype.onAdd = function(){
    // the Overlay dummy is ready and can be called upon
    delayedInit();
}
var dum;
```

... and after you've instantiated your Google map:

```js
dum = new Dummy(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I wound up in the same place after experimenting. Although, I just define the draw, onAdd and onRemove functions and leave them empty. Work like a charm! Thanks.